# How can I hide the soft keyboard in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

For an EditText view i can use setInputType(InputType.NULL), but an web view doesn't have it. I tried the rest of the solutions posted on stackoverflow but none of them worked for a web view.

Answer (score 0):

Does "the rest of the solutions posted" include adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` in the activity description of your manifest file?

Comment: Yes, and according to google that attribute isn't working on all android platforms. Here's  the link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7115

Comment: And you tried everything in the link at the bottom? Including the one with 49 upvotes?